# Detect current network on Phantom wallet

Tags: blockchain, solana, daap

I'm a newbie in solana blockchain. I'm integrating solana wallet (specifically Phantom wallet) into my website. Don't know if there is a way to determine which network the wallet is using (mainnet, devnet, testnet)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when it comes to determining which network a wallet like Phantom is connected to, the wallet itself doesn't directly expose this information. However, you can approach this in a few ways:

**Infer from the RPC Endpoint:** If you've set up your web application to connect to a specific RPC endpoint, you can infer which network the user should be connected to. For instance, if you're using https://api.devnet.solana.com, you can infer that you're connected to Devnet. You can then ask the user to ensure they're on the correct network in their Phantom wallet before making any transactions.

**Handle Transaction Errors Gracefully:** If a user tries to submit a transaction and they're on the wrong network, it will fail. While you can't preemptively detect the network, you can catch transaction errors and provide user-friendly feedback. For instance, if there's a failure, you might display a message suggesting the user check their wallet's network connection.

**Provide Clear Instructions:** On your website, you can give clear instructions to users to ensure they're on the desired network in their Phantom wallet before proceeding. This is a proactive approach to minimize potential confusion.